generate and unnest a list column of random values in polars using np.random.binomial()
I am trying to generate arrays of varying length within a polars dataframe (i.e., a list column).
For each cluster_id I would like to generate a series of 0s and 1s of length trials, which varies by cluster_id:
import numpy as np
import polars as pl
from polars import col

CLUSTERS = 200 
MEAN_TRIALS = 20
MU = 0.5
SIGMA = 0.1

df_cluster = pl.DataFrame({'cluster_id': range(1, CLUSTERS+1)}) 

df_cluster = df_cluster.with_columns(
    mu = stats.truncnorm(a=0, b=1, loc=MU, scale=SIGMA).rvs(size=CLUSTERS),
    trials = np.random.poisson(lam=MEAN_TRIALS, size=CLUSTERS)
)

I can use np.random.binomial() to generate a new column when size=1
df_cluster.with_columns(
    pl.struct(["mu", "trials"]).apply(lambda x: np.random.binomial(n=1, p=x['mu'], size=1)).alias('paid')
)

But I am unable to use np.random.binomial() to generate a new column when size=x['trials']
df_cluster.with_columns(
    pl.struct(["mu", "trials"]).apply(lambda x: np.random.binomial(n=1, p=x['mu'], size=x['trials'])).alias('paid')
)


Looks like a bug. It appears to run if I manually wrap it in a series: pl.Series(np.random.binomial(...))

You can actually create a function that will handle the logic of generating binomial lists based on the mu and trials values. This function checks if the trials are greater than zero to prevent errors.
import numpy as np
import polars as pl
from scipy.stats import truncnorm

CLUSTERS = 200
MEAN_TRIALS = 20
MU = 0.5
SIGMA = 0.1

df_cluster = pl.DataFrame({
    'cluster_id': range(1, CLUSTERS + 1)
})

mu_values = truncnorm(a=0, b=1, loc=MU, scale=SIGMA).rvs(size=CLUSTERS)
trials_values = np.random.poisson(lam=MEAN_TRIALS, size=CLUSTERS)

df_cluster = df_cluster.with_columns([
    pl.Series("mu", mu_values),
    pl.Series("trials", trials_values)
])

def generate_binomials(row):
    mu = row["mu"]
    trials = row["trials"]
    if trials > 0:
        return np.random.binomial(n=1, p=mu, size=trials).tolist()
    else:
        return []

df_cluster = df_cluster.with_columns(
    pl.col("mu").apply(lambda mu: mu).alias("mu"),
    pl.col("trials").apply(lambda trials: trials).alias("trials"),
    pl.struct(["mu", "trials"]).apply(generate_binomials).alias("paid")
)

print(df_cluster)


Which gives you
shape: (200, 4)
┌────────────┬──────────┬────────┬─────────────┐
│ cluster_id ┆ mu       ┆ trials ┆ paid        │
│ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---    ┆ ---         │
│ i64        ┆ f64      ┆ i64    ┆ list[i64]   │
╞════════════╪══════════╪════════╪═════════════╡
│ 1          ┆ 0.510534 ┆ 25     ┆ [1, 1, … 0] │
│ 2          ┆ 0.5514   ┆ 23     ┆ [0, 0, … 0] │
│ 3          ┆ 0.527765 ┆ 19     ┆ [0, 1, … 1] │
│ 4          ┆ 0.59992  ┆ 25     ┆ [0, 1, … 0] │
│ …          ┆ …        ┆ …      ┆ …           │
│ 197        ┆ 0.550822 ┆ 10     ┆ [1, 1, … 0] │
│ 198        ┆ 0.551411 ┆ 24     ┆ [1, 1, … 0] │
│ 199        ┆ 0.5924   ┆ 29     ┆ [0, 0, … 0] │
│ 200        ┆ 0.575209 ┆ 17     ┆ [0, 1, … 1] │
└────────────┴──────────┴────────┴─────────────┘

